# How to link docker container on Azure?

Tags: azure, docker

I would like to link two Docker containers deployed on Azure (ACS).
I have a container running the api server made in NodeJs and another container running Mongo.
I'd like to use something like "--link mymongodb" as I do on my pc, but there is no such parameter in az container create.
To create the containers I use this syntax:

```
az container create --name my-app --image myprivateregistry/my-app --resource-group MyResourceGroup --ports 80 --ip-address public
```

Probably I need to create a Virtual Network? 
Could you point me to the right direction please?

Comment: Please define "deployed on Azure"

Comment: Any more question? Or you can accept it.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I solved creating a virtual machine, installed docker and all worked as usual. I tried Azure Container Instance but I admit I had some problem with that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are searching the features like docker compose on Azure. If you want to use the Azure Container Instance, you should take a look at [Deploy a multi-container container group with YAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-multi-container-yaml) or with [Azure Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-multi-container-group). It will help you to create multi-container in a container group and the containers can connect to each other.

In addition, you can try with [Azure Kubernetes Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/intro-kubernetes), maybe it also can help you. If you need more help please give me the message.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify both images (your app and mongo) in an Azure yml file. It looks like a docker compose yml file, but it isn't.

Assuming your node.js app runs on port 3000, this could be a yml configuration for Azure container services:

```
apiVersion: 2018-06-01
location: westeurope
name: my-app-with-mongo
properties:
  containers:
  - name: mongodb
    properties:
      image: mongo
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1
          memoryInGb: 1.5
      ports:
      - port: 27017
  - name: my-app
    properties:
      image: myprivateregistry/my-app
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1
          memoryInGb: 1.5
      ports:
      - port: 3000
  osType: Linux
  ipAddress:
    type: Public
    dnsNameLabel: my-app
    ports:
    - protocol: tcp
      port: '3000'
  imageRegistryCredentials:
  - server: myprivateregistry.azurecr.io
    username: username-for-myprivateregistry
    password: password-for-myprivateregistry
tags: null
type: Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
```

Simply start it with

```
az container create --resource-group MyResourceGroup --file azure-container-group.yml
```

You can then access your mongo database on localhost:27017 as all containers run on the same host:

> Azure Container Instances supports the deployment of multiple
>   containers onto a **single host** by using a container group.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-multi-container-yaml

Also mind the order of the containers you specify in the yml file. You will want to start mongo first, then you node.js app as it probably wants to connect to mongo on start.